# Not able to throw exception for @override method

Tags: java, android, appium, guice

```
@Override
protected void configure() throws IOException{

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/properties/android.properties"));
        Names.bindProperties(binder(), props);


}
```

I am not able to throw any Exception for the above-overridden method. I'm getting error remove throw Exception. This is the implementation of a Guice module.

Comment: check your base class. `configure` method in it must be throwing IOException only. *Rule:* Overriding method can throw checked exception which is broader or new than those declared by the overridden method but it can not throw fewer or narrow checked exception.

Comment: configure is not throwing any exception. Can you please share a code snippet. It would great

Comment: Post your base class also. If it is not throwing any error you can not throw error in overriden methods. I suggest you read rules regarding throwing exceptions while overriding methods

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the `Module` interface, but you can work around it in several ways with Guice.

### You can wrap the exception:

```
try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/properties/android.properties")) {
   Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(in);
    Names.bindProperties(binder(), props);
} catch (IOException e) {
  // Yes, it's hard to create Guice exceptions. It's just like that.
  Message message = new Message(List.of(this), "Unable to load properties file", e);
  throw new ConfigurationException(List.of(message));
}
```

### You can move the file loading out of the module:

```
class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
  private final Properties properties;
  MyModule(Properties properties) {
    this.properties = properties;
  }
  @Override protected void configure() {
    Names.bind(binder(), props);
  }
}
```

And create your module like this. Normally you should be able to throw your exceptions outside the module implementations.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
try (InputStream in = FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/properties/android.properties")) {
  properties.load(in);
}
Module module = new MyModule(properties);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you added same throws IOException on parent Method ?

If you override the method and if original method signature don't have Throws IOException then it will not work .

i.e

```java
interface A {

  void A() throws Exception;

}

class B implements A{

  @override
  public void A() throws Exception{
  }

}
```

the above format will work.

Comment: keep in mind that the default access modifier of an interface is public, while that of a class is protected. If you don't specify the 'public' on the class implementation, it won't compile.

Comment: OP cannot change the interface: it's part of Guice, hence the tag.